# lerp vector2 to target vector2 at constant rate

Tags: mathematics, lerp

I am struggling to figure out how to lerp one vector2 to a target vector2 at a constant rate. I can do it as a percentage of the total x, y distance like so:

```
lerp(start, current, target, pctSpeed) {
  return current + pctSpeed * (target - start);
}
```

calling it as such:

```
speed = .02

// game loop
Update(timestamp) {
  x = lerp(startX, x, targetX, speed)
  y = lerp(startY, y, targetY, speed)
  resultingVector2 = {x: x, y: y}
}
```

which correctly lerps x and y by 2% of the distance between the start and target vector2 each frame. How do you do this at a constant rate, i.e instead of 2% a value of 2 or .2 or 3, etc. Thanks

Comment: If the function interpolates target vector by 2% of target vector, you are interpolating it at costant rate already.

Comment: True, the behavior I am trying to avoid is that for larger distances the interpolation will occur more quickly than for shorter distances in terms of speed as it is percentage based. 2% of 1000 is > 2% of 25. I would rather like it to be a fixed distance interpolation, say of 5 instead of 2% of the total distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not redefining a common method like Lerp. Linear interpolation has a standard definition:

```
Lerp(a, b, t) {
    return (1-t) * a + t * b;
}
```

If you redefine it to describe any old movement along a line, your code will become very hard to understand for anyone who's used to this standard.

Instead, if you want to move at a constant speed, define a new method for that:

```
Approach(current, target, maxStepDistance) {
    toTarget = target - current;

    // Clamp our travel so we never move further than our allowed step.
    squareMagnitude = dot(toTarget, toTarget);
    if(squareMagnitude > maxStepDistance * maxStepDistance) {
        toTarget *= maxStepDistance/sqrt(squareMagnitude)
    }

    return current + toTarget;
}
```

Which you can use like so:

```
Update(timestamp) {
    // Make sure you're using a high precision source for your timestamp
    // when calculating deltaTime - a float will lose precision after hours of play.
    deltaTime = timeStamp - lastFrameTimestamp;
    lastFrameTimestamp = timestamp;

    // Multiply speed by the timestep to get the distance travelled this frame.
    current = Approach(current, target, speed * deltaTime);
}
```